# ADUser assign specific department if null

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add users to a department when they are in a specific OU.
But I don't want to overwrite the users / alter them when it is not null. Because I don't want my file to grow.

How should I correct this?

```
$textfile=get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
Start-Transcript -Path "c:\results\location A\$textfile.txt"
Write-Host "Assigning / re-assigning users to a OU specific department..." -ForegroundColor Yellow


Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "ou=Users,ou=Location A,ou=organization,dc=fabrikam,dc=com" | 
ForEach-Object {
$user = $_
        if ($user.Department -ne $null) {
                try {
                Set-ADUser $user -Department "Location A"
                Write-Host $user.Name"moved to department" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
                } 
                catch { 
                Write-Host "Error occured" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Black 
                }
        }
}
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please define what you **expect** the script to do and what is wrong with the **actual** behavior. As a sidenote: [**`$null` should be on left side of equality comparison**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1021): `if ($Null -eq $user.Department) {...`

Comment: Thanks, if I execute this script for the very first time I expect the destination to become "Location A" and a output is generated of the users that are adjusted. However when the script is run for the next day I want only the new users (or the users without department) to be changed and logged. The existing users or the users with a department already set should not be modified or added to the txt file. At this moment I keep getting:
Assigning users to a OU specific department...
user1 moved to department
user2 moved to department. The next run should not include user1 or user2.

Comment: The script is working fine, however it is not filtering the users with a existing department.

Comment: Please put that information in the question (not in the comments) so that other also have a good understanding of the issue and what you expect.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to move only users that do **NOT** have a Department attribute filled in, so in that case shouldn't your test be `if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.Department)) {..}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common question about the mysteries of active directory filters.  This filter will return objects with null department properties.

```
get-aduser -filter "department -notlike '*'" -ResultSetSize 5 -property department
```

Answer (score 0):

as @js2010 pointed out, `Get-ADUser` will retrieve only a very few subset of AD properties, department, is not one of them, so when you test it, it will be always null. To avoid this add `-Properties department` parameter to `Get-ADUser`. (You should prefer his filter too, just add the searchbase you want)

But there is another problem if you want to test this after as you did, your condition is reverted : you are testing to replace only values that are already defined, `-eq`will be better ;) as @iRon said, you should prefer `$null -eq $user.department` than `$user.department -eq $null` (@Theo's one is fine too)